# Where Physically SQL Server Stored Procedure objects stored in System

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know that SQL Server Stored Procedure Stored in Folder which is inside Programmability. But I want to know Stored Procedures Object where it is stored in physical system.

Comment: Are you asking for where the procedures are stored physically in the tablespace or where in the sys.* tables? Check out sys.* table documentation (e.g. sys.objects) if you want to get meta data and program code of your stored procedures.

Comment: I am asking for where user defined stored procedures stored in Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [resource database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx):

> SQL Server system objects, such as sys.objects, are physically
>   persisted in the Resource database, but they logically appear in the
>   sys schema of every database.

They're all read only and you cannot access the resource database directly, so is all academic. Why do you want to know?

General metadata about a database objects is available in the [Object Catalog Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Remus, But can we view that metadata, if yes then can you please let me know from where i will get all to view.

Comment: [@San20130121](http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires): How about use [`SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I got the info what i want exactly.